# Accessing nested objects in django POST request using python 3

Tags: python, json, django

I am having some trouble accessing nested objects from an ajax post call. Here is my js:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/locate/",
    type: "POST",
    data: {start:
        {
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude
        }
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
        console.log(start);
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
})
```

in my views, the only way I can retrieve the data is by doing the following:

```
latitude = request.POST['start[latitude]']
longitude = request.POST['start[longitude]']
```

which is kinda bad considering that optimally I'd like to have start as the dictionary containing the latitude and longitude keys. I do realize this formatting is due to the content type being set to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", but when I change it to "application/json", the data must be decoded from request.body:

```
decoded = request.body.decode('utf8')
data = json.loads(decoded)
```

which in turn raises the following ValueError:

Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

The decoded string is:

start%5B0%5D%5Blatitude%5D=31.736784000000004&start%5B0%5D%5Blongitude%5D=-106.473027

Has any of you had any luck on properly loading nested objects or am I stuck with the first method?

EDIT: Using Django 1.6.2 and python 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send json data, use the JSON stringifier on your object.

```
data: JSON.stringify({start:
        {
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude
        }
    })
```

If you pass a plain Object as data, [*it is converted to a query string*](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings), no matter what you declare as Content-Type.